# redhat linux 6 / disk space at 100% after delete and reboot

Tags: linux, redhat

Using df -h and du my disk space show 100% all the time. I have deleted at least 2GB of files and I rebooted the server. I thought that will fix the issue as the server came up just fine. However, it still shows disk space at 100%.

Have anyone has this issue before? I have a tomcat and mysql running on both server. I have stopped those also. I have no idea what to do now?

Comment: How about providing the output of your 'df' and 'du' commands that you ran? We can't really help you unless you provide the diagnostic information that you've already gathered.

Comment: How big is the filesystem?  Greater the 400GB perhaps?  If ext* the output of `tune2fs -l /dev/devicename` would be useful.

Comment: The HDD is 320GB here is df -h result;                                                               /dev/sda1   size:20G Used:20G Avail:0  Use%:100% Mountedon:/                                                           /dev/sda6  20G 113M  19G 1%  mountedon:/root2                                                      /dev/sda5   185G 540M 175G 1% mountedon:/var

Comment: You can edit your question and add more details you know.  It will be a lot easier to read there.  You say you deleted 2GB of files.  Did you actually remove files that were on the root filesystem?  Use a command like `du --max-depth=1 -x -h /` to hunt down what is taking up space.

Answer (score 0):

You should also run `fsck` on the filesystem and reclaim any lost inodes. If you delete a large file with an open handle, the filehandle remains valid and the inode doesn't get reclaimed. Running fsck can fix this.

Comment: I found the issue thanks . my tomcat was logging like crazy ihad 16GB of log on the tomcat.Even when i stop teh tomcat it still logged.Had to remove the whole thing. Thanks